# Function inside a with() statement doesn't receive the defined object

Tags: javascript, function

When I define and call a Function from within a with() statement, the function doesn't receive the object defined in the with(). Is there a way to solve my problem?

For example, this code doesn't work:

```
var testObj = { testStr: "Hello World!" };
with(testObj) {
  function testFunc(){
     alert(testStr);
  }
  testFunc();
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `with`? Not saying it's entirely forbidden of course, but it is generally considered best avoided.

Comment: Not *entirely* forbidden but [forbidden in ECMAScript 5's strict mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/).

Comment: @RightSaidFred I need to use jQuery and a set of functions in a Firefox Mobile (Fennec) extension, where the web page is inside an object called "content".

BTW aren't you too sexy for stackoverflow?

Comment: @benkol: So sexy it hurts... But yeah, it would be better to just use a direct reference to the object somehow, but if you were to use `with`, you'd [want a function expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8402739/376743) instead of a declaration.

Comment: FWIW, I ran into this issue while developing a templating engine that uses `with` so that it can compile the template once then execute it on multiple inputs… And I was hit by this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a function declaration.

Functions shouldn't be declared in statement blocks in the first place.

An expression will work:

```
var testObj = { testStr: "Hello World!" };
with(testObj) {
  var testFunc  = function(){
     alert(testStr);
  }
  testFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a function expression:

```
var testObj = { testStr: "Hello World!" };
with(testObj) {
  var testFunc = function(){
     alert(testStr);
  };
  testFunc();
}
```

Function declarations are hoisted so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's pointing to the testFunc(), and not testObj.

```
var testObj = { testStr: "Hello World!" };
with(testObj) {
    function testFunc(){
        alert(this == testObj);
    }
    testFunc();
}
```

Comment: `this` is likely the global object, and `testObj` is the object. The issue is with having a function declaration where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use `with`[(1)](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html):

```
var testObj = { testStr: "Hello World!" };
(function() {
  alert(testObj.testStr);
}())
```

Comment: Yes it does. "Is there a way to solve my problem?" is the question. "Don't do it that way" is a perfectly valid answer to the question.